# How to redirect http://internal.example.com/ to http://internal.example.com/?q=user in Drupal

Tags: drupal-7

I want to redirect http://internal.example.com/  to http://internal.example.com/?q=user in Drupal7.

I have tried both htaccess and php header location redirect but did not work.

Please let me know how to do it in Drupal and where to place which code in which directory. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you want to accomplish with this? Do you want users to log in before they access the website?

Comment: Basically I want to Redirect
http://internal.example.com/  (Blank Page Right now)
to
http://internal.example.com/?q=user (User Login Page)

 http://internal.example.com/?q=user  is the login page where user can add username and password @Ronald Bijker

Comment: You could try to uncheck the option "View published content" for anonymous users in admin/people/permissions. Normally the login form will now be shown to not logged in users when they try to access any page.